# How to do such string manipulations in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I need to convert

```
 "01,02,03,04,05,07:01"
```

to:

```
<b>07</b><b>09</b><b>30</b><b class="color_blue_ball">11</b>
```

That is ,wrap those before `:` with `<b></b>` ,but those after `:` with `<b class="color_blue_ball"></b>`.If there's no `:`,all should be wrapped with `<b></b>`

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Have you *tried* to do this? If so, how?

Comment: So, is this a valid scenario too: `01,02,03,04,05,07:01,04,06` ?

Comment: What about the mapping between the input and output numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tad more verbose:

```
<?php
function wrapValues($array, $wrapper) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array as $elem) {
    $result []= str_replace('?', $elem, $wrapper);
  }   
  return implode('', $result);
}

$values = "01,02,03,04,05,07:01,02";
$firstWrapper = '<b>?</b>';
$secondWrapper = '<b class="color_blue_ball">?</b>';

list($first, $second) = explode(':', $values);

echo wrapValues(explode(',', $first), $firstWrapper) . 
     wrapValues(explode(',', $second), $secondWrapper);
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for regex:

```
echo '<b>' . str_replace(array(',', ':'), array('</b><b>', '</b><b class="color_blue_ball">'),  "01,02,03,04,05,07:01") . '</b>';
```

**Edit**: if the "01,02,03,04,05,07:01,04,06" is valid, then the idea the same but `explode` is added:

```
$parts = explode(':', "01,02,03,04,05,07,01,04:06");
echo '<b>' . str_replace(',', '</b><b>', $parts[0]) . (isset($parts[1]) ? str_replace(',', '</b><b class="color_blue_ball">',  ',' . $parts[1]) : '') . '</b>';
```

Comment: Clever, but this scenario might also occur if I interpreted the questioners question correctly: `01,02,03,04,05,07:01,04,06`

Comment: I think `, ',' . $parts[1]) :` should read: `, $parts[1]) :`. Other than that: good answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but I would probably split the string on the `:`, then on `,`, and then deal with each part separately and join them back together.